# How to make a List<> of a type obtained with GetType("Class Name") at runtime?

Tags: c#

I'm implementing something dynamic that doesn't require to add X lines of code every time I add a feature

I have different lists of different classes

I can access what I want by doing

```cs
List<AutoPath> temp = (List<AutoPath>)typeof(QuestActions).GetProperty("autoPath").GetValue(Quests.Actions, null);
```

Which is great, I can access a `List<>` in a different class by it's name and get / change the content

But now I want to combine this with `GetType()`

```cs
Type t = Type.GetType("ChineeseRevolution.Actions.AutoPath");
```

I tried doing

```cs
Type t = Type.GetType("ChineeseRevolution.Actions.AutoPath");
List<t> temp = (List<t>)typeof(QuestActions).GetProperty("autoPath").GetValue(Quests.Actions, null);
```

But it doesn't let me

It is at runtime

To summarise:
- I have the name of a public `List<>` in another class
- I want to modify any list of that class with it's name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create List<T> using GetType()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454382/create-listt-using-gettype)

Comment: Or seems like _to add X lines of code every time_ would be quicker and simpler to use ;)

Comment: You cannot declare a *variable* that is "some *specific* type that I won't know until runtime". You can of course declare it as `object` or `dynamic` but of course you then lose intellisense, etc.

Comment: I don't agree with the suggested dupe since the OP here seems to be trying to get hold of an *existing* list, not create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend you won't know the type at compile time, but that someone else will know the type at *their* compile time. If that were the case, you could write a generic method that accepts the type as a type parameter:

```
static void DoSomethingWithList<TList>()
{
  var list =  (List<TList>)typeof(QuestActions)
       .GetProperty("autoPath")
       .GetValue(Quests.Actions, null);
  //Do stuff with List
}
```

And then this other code that knows it at their compile time can call this method.

But, you object, that's not the situation here - you're the one who won't know the type until runtime. But that's no problem for us to introduce a little "bridging" here. In another method, we do:

```
  var t = Type.GetType("ChineeseRevolution.Actions.AutoPath");
  var x = Expression.Call(
     typeof(Program).GetMethod(
     nameof(DoSomethingWithList),
     System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
     .MakeGenericMethod(t));
  var y = Expression.Lambda(x);
  y.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Where `System.Linq.Expressions` is assumed to be in a using directive above this code and `Program` is the class containing `DoSomethingWithList`. We've introduced a *small* amount of expression-based-magic to get us a small "extra" round of compile time and to jump across the divide.

If you have more types, try to get them all done in one "jump" from "known at runtime" to "generic parameters". If you have additional parameters that you need to come along for the ride it's a little more work in setting up the call and the lambda, but I'll not go into the details here.